# Apache Spark Simulator

Tags: apache-spark, nosql, bigdata

Can Spark in standalone mode be used as a simulator or Databricks community edition for research purposes? I want to simulate an idea because I do not have access to a physical cluster for my research on optimizing Spark Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Spark Local Mode and be able to run Spark as library in local mode from IDE and debug.